# how to get new mail notifications from Gmail accounts using Push notifications

Tags: android, push-notification, gmail

I'm getting confused with Push notifications for Gmail for android app.
I'm trying build a notifier which notifies user if there is a new mail in his gmail account.
How can i implement without pooling, and with Gmail API only?

Answer (score 0):

Gmail API does not support this. You will have to check manually for new email. Also there are not documented broadcasts for gmail's new message arrivals.